# How to access doubly nested models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route that looks like this

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers do
      resources :comments
  end
end
```

However, when I try to build a comment

```
 <%= form_for([@answer, @answer.comments.build]) do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :comment %>
    <%= f.text_area :comment, :cols => "50", :rows => "30"%>
</p>
<p>
```

I get undefined method comments. This is what my create comment looks like

```
    def create
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
    @comment = @answer.comments.create(params[:comment])
        redirect_to question_path(@question)
end
```

And answer has_many comments, and comments belongs to answer. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what do u have in your controller "new" action

Comment: don't have a new action, as the form for a new comment is displayed on another view

Comment: did you run the migration?

Comment: Try comment.build (rather than comments.build)

Answer (score 0):

You can access models from any controller in your app (just call `Model.class_method`)

---

Looking at your code, I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
#app/views/answers/show.html.erb 
<% @answer.comments.each do |comment| %>
   <%= comment.value %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @new_comment do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_area :comment, :cols => "50", :rows => "30"%>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
def new
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    @new_comment = Comment.new
end


#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.save
end

private
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:your, :attributes, :here)
end
```